# Find Replace Text in a File Name - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i have a need to replace different string in file names. Is there a way to modify a file name using a find replace function in Powershell?

I have done this in a .bat file but would for this to be done in PS instead.

Comment: i know that will get the all the text in a file, but i just want to do the find replace on the file name itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find characters and rename file name using Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647578/find-characters-and-rename-file-name-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any details so here's a generic example:

```
$pattern = "foo"

# Getting all files that match $pattern in a folder.
# Add '-Recurse' switch to include files in subfolders.
$search_results = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\folder" `
    | Where-Object { ((! $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -match $pattern)) } 

foreach ($file in $search_results) {
    $new_name = $file.Name -replace $pattern, "bar"

    # Remove '-WhatIf' switch to commit changes.
    Rename-Item -WhatIf -Path $file.FullName -NewName $new_name
}
```

Note that `$pattern` will be treated as a regular expression so escape special characters if you need to catch them.

Comment: exactly was i was looking for, sorry for the vagueness of the question.  Thanks you

Comment: You can simplify this by piping directly to rename-item and using a scriptblock e.g. `... | Where {...} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $pattern,'bar'} -whatif`.