# Powershell Bulk Rename of Files from csv list with dynamic names

Tags: powershell

I have a large number of xls files with four digits at the start of the name, a generic body, a dynamic month, year, and extraction date at the end of the filename.

For example: 9999_Generic_Name_Here_Oct_2017_05102017.xls

I need to rename these files, replacing the first four digits with a corresponding three character alphanumeric code, but keep the rest of the filename and extension the same. Each month there will be a new batch of files with a different month and different extraction date.

I have been trying to manipulate the following code to work with -like and wildcards but I have been hitting brick walls.

```
Import-Csv "C:\data\Rename_Files.csv" | foreach { Rename-Item -Path $_.Path -NewName $_.NewName }
```

In the Rename_Files.csv I have two columns with the path / original name and new name.

How do I use the above code to do this, or is there a better way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming file name in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411056/find-replace-text-in-a-file-name-powershell#25412484)

Comment: I'm not sure how $pattern will help @VenkataramanR If I use pattern = Generic_Name_Here I still don't know how I will keep the trailing mmm_yyyy and extraction date, nor how I work into it the renaming of the first four digits.

Comment: "*I have been hitting brick walls.*" - like what? You have the original name and .. oh you say you have the original name but I guess you don't have it? How much of it do you have and in what form?

Comment: Only "Generic_Name_Here" and ".xls" extension will be constant and known.

Comment: Consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did it instead with JREN which is a hybrid JScript/batch utility.